# Add functions to the callback's condition list in the module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have:

- a controller with before_filter callback defined (**UPDATE** : controller is in rails application and I can't modify it)
- a module with some new functions, which is added to the controller (**UPDATE** : module is in my plugin)

I want this callback to execute before those functions too.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :prepare, :only => :show

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  private

  def prepare
  end
end 

module MyModule  
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    base.before_filter :prepare, :only => [:a, :b]
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def a
      ...
    end
    def b
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

If I do it this way, the list will be redefined, and "prepare" wouldn't be called before "show".

The options I see:

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    base.before_filter :prepare, :only => [:a, :b, :show]
  end
```

or

```
    def a
      prepare
      ...
    end
    def b
      prepare
      ...
    end
```

or

```
module MyModule  
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    base.before_filter :prep, :only => [:a, :b]
  end
  module InstanceMethods
    def prep
      prepare
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

are SO ugly and un-DRY.

Is there any natural way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should

```
before_filter :prepare, :except => [:foo, :bar, :etc]
```

Which I think will pick up `:a` and `:b`.

BTW, your controller seems like it might be pretty fat. Perhaps, also, an opportunity for refactoring?

Comment: What tells you that the controller is fat?

Comment: It was just a thought I had given the use of a module to include additional methods. Which suggests to me (perhaps wrongly) that there might be a lot going on in the controller. And, thus, perhaps an opportunity to re-think some design. But, perhaps not and perhaps the controller is skinny-as-can-be.

Comment: Controller is from vendor rails application (so I do not want to touch it) and module is in my plugin. The list of functions in controller may change, so I do not want to screw it up on future application updates.

Comment: Fair enough. Context helps a lot. If the `:except` bit doesn't work for you, I suggest you add the further context to your OP so that other potential answers can take it into account as they try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
module MyModule  
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def prepare(*actions)
      # optional - add defaults
      actions = ([:a, :b] + (actions || [])).uniq
      # self here is the singelton class object
      self.instance_eval do
        before_filter :prep, only: actions
      end
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def prep
      prepare
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

We create a `prepare` class method which takes a splat and then evaluates a before_filter with the splat of actions merged with defaults.

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  include MyModule
  prepare :show
end
```